# Is it possible to pipe a list into ggsave

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, ggsave

This works, requires however to create a variable (p):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

p <- mtcars %>% 
  split(.$cyl) %>% 
    map(~.x %>% ggplot(aes(x=hp,y=qsec)) + geom_point()) 
  
ggsave(filename = "myPlot.pdf", 
       device = "pdf",
       plot = marrangeGrob(p, nrow=1, ncol=1), 
       width = 15, height = 9)
```

What  I woudl like to do is something like this (code below gives an error):

```
mtcars %>% 
  split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~.x %>% ggplot(aes(x=hp,y=qsec)) + geom_point()) %>% 
    ggsave(filename = "myPlot.pdf", 
           device = "pdf",
           plot = marrangeGrob(., nrow=1, ncol=1), 
           width = 15, height = 9)

Thanks!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `{..}` around the last code block -

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

mtcars %>% 
  split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~.x %>% ggplot(aes(x=hp,y=qsec)) + geom_point()) %>% 
  {  ggsave(filename = "myPlot.pdf", 
         device = "pdf",
         plot = marrangeGrob(., nrow=1, ncol=1), 
         width = 15, height = 9)
  }
```

Comment: perfect, works! Thanks!